# APK is not found after successful 'ionic cordova build android' command

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to deploy my ionic project by following steps on [this tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/play-store). 
When I want to run `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` the build return successful but the APK doesn't found on the default folder `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk`. However,  the build folder itself wasn't found.

the result of `ionic cordova build android`:

```
✔ cordova build android - done!
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/huthaifah/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
> Task :wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
```

My ionic environment:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.0

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.4 ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node  : v8.9.0
    npm   : 5.5.1 
    OS    : macOS
    Xcode : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

the strcutre of my android platform as shown:

[image]

Comment: Do the results for —prod —release tags build successful as well?

Comment: Yes, it returns successful result, but the apk from this result doesn't not exist

Comment: Yeah it should build the apk for you. You might want to try removing the android platform and then re add it.

Comment: I tried removing the platform and add it many times, unfortunately, the problem is still unsolved. The main problem is that no logs with details to trace the problem. the command also returns success.